# Does Tokyo Cabinet support in-memory B+ Tree implementation?

Tags: tokyo-cabinet, kyotocabinet, tokyo-tyrant

Does Tokyo Cabinet support in-memory B+ trees? If so, how do I use them? Because in some web articles (for example [here](http://korrespondence.blogspot.it/2009/09/tokyo-tyrant-tuning-parameters.html) and [here](http://capttofu.livejournal.com/23381.html)), such usage is reported but I can't find any document describing how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, the mythical "some article I found" article.

Comment: @MarcB, I modify my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/spex-en.html) describes tcadbopen(TCADB *adb, const char *name) as follows:

> `name' specifies the name of the database.
>   If it is "*", the database will be an on-memory hash database.
>   If it is "+", the database will be an on-memory tree database.

So, the name "+" does what you want.

Comment: I try that:  means HDB hdb = new HDB();
    if(!hdb.open("+", HDB.OWRITER | HDB.OCREAT)). But, it creates a DB named +.

Comment: The magic for + and * is only available via the abstract interface (-> tcadbopen).

Comment: No, the abstract interface is available at the C level, see section "The Abstract Database API" in the documentation. If you are using a binding for another language, the binding could be incomplete. So please consider completing it.

Answer (score 1):

You will also find a good overview of the possibilities of Tokyo Tyrant here: http://korrespondence.blogspot.fr/2009/09/tokyo-tyrant-tuning-parameters.html